# Transform a wff to a prenex normal form

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Could you help solve this problem. I need to convert the following wff to a PNF

∀x(L(x)->∃x M(x,y))
I do not understand how universal quantifier and existential quantifier on same variable operate. Scope of ∀x includes ∃x M(x,y) too.

Thanks to help

Comment: Can you more clearly state what you are asking? And format the question using mathjax.

Comment: Edted the question. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not working on the same variable.
In $∀x(L(x)->∃x M(x,y))$, the outer variable $x$ is bounded to the all-quantifier. In  $\exists x[M(x,y)]$, $x$ is bounded by the existential quantifier. You could rename it such as in $∀x(L(x)->∃z M(z,y))$. On the other hand, $y$ is a free variable.

Comment: But, the scope of ∀x includes ∃xM(x,y), would that not be a problem while renaming?